# cancel HTA close after user clicks close button

Tags: javascript, events, hta

Many programs prompt users if they really want to exit after clicking the window exit button (the big red X in the upper right corner of the window). In HTML Applications (HTA files), we can do it too.

However, I don't know how to cancel the close event that comes after the onbeforeunload. I tried **event.preventDefault()**, **event.stopPropagation()**, **event.cancelBubble = true**, **window.event.bubbling = false**, **return false**, but neither worked.

Example:

```
<head>
<title>Cancel Close</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ask() {
        var answer = confirm("Quit program?");
        if (answer) {
            alert("Exiting...");
        } else {

            //window.event.preventDefault(); //method does not exist
            //window.event.stopPropagation(); //method does not exist

            window.event.cancelBubble = true; //quits anyway
            window.event.bubbling = false; //quits anyway
            return false; //quits anyway
        }
    }
</script>

<body bgcolor="#ECE9D8" style="overflow:auto" onbeforeunload="ask()">
    Some HTML... Click exit and cancel; the program exits anyway, but should not.
</body>
```

How to cancel the close operation if the user clicks cancel?

Comment: use a higher IE version with edge meta. IE10+ lets you use real events. you also need to bind _beforeunload_ to _window_, not <body>. you also need to return a string in onbeforeunload, which the user can see.

Comment: Had a difficult time figuring out what to do according to your comment, but finally managed to do it. A new window, default from IE, appears trying to confirm if i really want to quit, but again, no matter if i cancel or not, it quits.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of, sorry. well at least with better IE you have more features... One last idea: depending on your app, you might be able serialize all the state onunload and then relaunch a new app with all the same settings from an onunload event. make sure `singleinstance` HTA setting is false if you want to do that. that way, the app still closes, but it appears as though it just blinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible in .hta apllications. You can try alternative solution to hide close button and create close button into page. Here is your example code edited:

```
<head>
<title>Cancel Close</title>
<hta:application sysmenu="no"/>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ask() {
        var answer = confirm("Quit program?");
        if (answer) {
            alert("Exiting...");
        } else {

            //window.event.preventDefault(); //method does not exist
            //window.event.stopPropagation(); //method does not exist

            window.event.cancelBubble = true; //quits anyway
            window.event.bubbling = false; //quits anyway
            return false; //quits anyway
        }
    }
</script>

<body bgcolor="#ECE9D8" style="overflow:auto" onbeforeunload="ask()">
    Some HTML... Click exit and cancel; the program exits anyway, but should not.
</body>
```

You can check application object reference
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
There are very specific things about these .htа applications.

Comment: Yes, I know the htа:application tag, it is a good idea to create a custom button. But I'll lose the maximize and minimize buttons, whose functionality I don't know to recreate. Any clues?

Comment: I've found a way to maximize and minimize with internal buttons and javascript. So, this answer is what I'll be impementing.